# Mutator runs on update but cell data unchanged

Tags: tabulator

I want to create a new field `reservationAction` and put into my table as a column `Reservation` defined as:

```
{title: "Reservation", field: "reservationAction", mutator: reservationMutator},
```

with `reservationMutator` as:

```
var reservationMutator = function(value, data, type, params, component) {
    console.log(data);
    if (!data.checkoutable) return null;
    if (data.is_reserved) {
        return "Free";
    }
    return "Get";
}
```

`is_reserved` and `checkoutable` are pre-existing fields of my data.

When the page initially loads, and table is created using `ajax`, the cell shows the correct string for `Reservation`. When `is_reserved` is changed server-side, I call `table.updateOrAddData([newData])` (as part of websocket event-handler).

The problem:
When `table.updateOrAddData([newData])` run, I can see the custom mutator get triggered
and from the `console.log()` line, see that the `reservationAction` is correctly set in the log. **But the table itself is showing the old value.** Other (non-mutating) columns are updated on the table as expected. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

If instead I use `table.replaceData()`, then both console, and table show correct value. But I would want to avoid doing this on each websocket event for performance reasons.

Version: I've tried all 5+.

Any help would be appreciated!

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teds20h1/2/)

Comment: do you have a link to a JS Fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: i'll try to create one sure, and post it here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/teds20h1/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is a workaround or how I'm actually supposed to do it in the first place but, doing `row.reformat()` seems to do what I expect. Oh well.

```
table.updateOrAddData([row_obj])
    .then(function(rows){
        rows.forEach(row => {
            row.reformat();
        });
    });
```